# How can I have doc/docstrip output more than one file?

Tags: documentation

I am trying to use `doc\docstrip` to write a small package. I have one main class `.dtx`, which is processed via an `.ins` file. 
Is it possible to include two small test files in the `.dtx` file and generate them  via the `doc/docstrip` method or do I have to write them as separate files.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks a lot. I will have a look at your package. Will you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Put the code of the test file between tags, say

```
%<*testa>
code for the first test
%</testa>
```

and say, in the `.ins` file,

```
\generate{\file{testa.tex}{\from{mypackage.dtx}{testa}}}
```

Notice that a single `\generate` can have many `\file` statements.

There are many examples in the directories under `source/latex`.